# Keep order in Sankey diagram when applying filters in Power Bi

Tags: powerbi, sankey-diagram

I have a basic Sankey diagram with weights. I ordered the nodes manually.
[Sankey without filters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuK1Z.png)

When I apply a filter the order is moved and nodes are overlapped:
[Sankey with filters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TH0t0.png)

Is there a way to keep the order of the nodes and prevent them from moving when applying a filter?

Hope the community can help me with this

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. In some cases, the Sankey will also change the custom selected colors.

A (partial) solution I have found is that you can modify each 'state' of the chart. So in the editor, you filter the data and adjust to the way you want the chart to look. If you do this for each potential filtered state of the chart, the chart seems to remember all of the settings.

Unfortunately, this solution is impractical for situations in which there are many categories in the Sankey and many filtered states of the chart.

Hope this helps.